# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( code=2,address=0x0) { Inside switch case}

Tags: iphone, ios5

I have created a navigation controller with two viewcontrollers in storboard. The first viewcontroller has a start button from where I segued to second viewcontroller. Inside the secondviewcontroller I have placed a segment control which has three segments with titles: Man , Truck , Movie.

Declared and defined setActiveModel method inside the implementation file of second viewcontroller. This method has switch case for three segments in segmentcontrol.

and finally inside the IBaction for segment control called this setActivemethod.

```
- (void) setActiveModel: (int) modelIndex
{
    switch ( modelIndex )
    {
        case 0:
            m_truckModel->setVisible(false); **---->>[ I get BAD_ACCESS error in this line which steps over in the debugger to viewdidload method to the line where I initialize setActiveModel to integer 0 ]    <<-----**
            m_metaioMan->setVisible(true);

            // stop the movie
            m_moviePlane->stopMovieTexture();
            m_moviePlane->setVisible(false);
            m_moviePlaneButton->setVisible(false);
            break;

        case 1:
            m_truckModel->setVisible(true);
            m_metaioMan->setVisible(false);           

            // stop the movie
            m_moviePlane->stopMovieTexture();
            m_moviePlane->setVisible(false);
            m_moviePlaneButton->setVisible(false);
            break;

        case 2:
            m_truckModel->setVisible(false);
            m_metaioMan->setVisible(false);

            m_moviePlane->setVisible(false);
            m_moviePlaneButton->setVisible(true);
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)onSegmentControlChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
{
    [self setActiveModel:sender.selectedSegmentIndex];
}
```

Comment: [ I get BAD_ACCESS error in this line which steps over in the debugger to viewdidload method to the line where I initialize setActiveModel to integer 0 ]    <<-----

Comment: your m_truckModel was released before reaching that line of code. check (and) post how you intialize m_truckModel and how you release it.
Is it being autoreleased?

Comment: I'd suggest running your app in Instruments (and choosing Zombie). My guess is that m_truckModel is somewhere released more than it is retained (are you using ARC?)

Comment: Your m_truckModel is released somewhere before your switch, that's why you got an exec_bad_access.

There are two things you can try:

1> create a description for your m_truckModel and set a break point right on your switch. Then by using `po m_truckModel` in the command line you can see what's actually there. And you can follow your logic and set more break points on the way to see where your m_truckModel object got released.

2> use Instruments - Zombie, and it will capture the exec_bad_access on your m_truckModel object and exactly where it got released. And this is a better way to do.

Comment: @user1071136- Hi I am not using ARC in fact since i am using obj c/c++ code inside a storyboard app thats why have disabled ARC as code contains release statements. For both the viewcontrollers implementation file I have disabled ARC [ under Build phases-> Compile source-> select respective .mm file and set -fno-objc-arc ]

Comment: I am not initializing these models setActiveModel method is used to select the switch case initially its starting with case 0. And that's why the ViewDidLoad() method contains the statement.  [self setActiveModel:0];

Comment: I am new to xcode can someone guide me to right link dont know how to use instruments - Zombie

Answer (score 1):

You can use Instruments to find out the where the over release happened in the code. 
Here is the link on how to use Instruments. 
[Eliminating Messages To Deallocated Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-memory-allocations-help/Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects/06_Eliminating_Messages_To_Deallocated_Objects.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried to use

```
[self.m_truckModel setVisible:NO];
```

Its a little strange coding way.
You should review the storyboard also.